# How to overwrite npy file and save it in a directory?

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to save a numpy file in a specific directory and overwrite it. How can i do this?

```
path = os.path.join(data_path, created_folder, 'testone')
with open('{}.npy'.format('testone'), 'ab') as f:
     np.save(f, mydata)
```

Comment: Use `'w+b'` instead of `'ab'` for the mode specifier - `a` is for appending - see the docs ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: just give the filename to `save`.  You don't need the `with open` for simple use like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code opens the file for *appending* and you didn't give it the correct path you defined. To overwrite it, use the mode `w` like this:

```py
path = os.path.join(data_path, created_folder, 'testone')
with open('{}.npy'.format(path), 'wb') as f:
     np.save(f, mydata)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Thank you for your help. But If i use `wb` It shows that the created Numpy file has 2KB of memory. But when I use `ab` I see that the memory size of my Numpy array gets bigger, which actually shows that data is being overwritten there, or am I wrong?

Comment: `ab` is appending new data to your file, not over-writing it like you need, so it should be increasing it each time. Try to immediately read back in the saved array like this: `np.loadz(path)` and confirm the written array can be read back correctly.